# Calculate the number of lines matching the pattern Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to write a script on Bash that does:

I have a file, that consists of string like this:

```
2002-02-15 00:01:19 217.21.43.21 RES company_name
2002-02-15 00:01:19 217.21.43.21 RES company_name
2002-02-15 00:01:19 217.21.43.21 DEL company_name
2002-02-13 00:01:19 217.21.43.21 RES company_name
```

I need to calculate the number of requests with parameter `RES` for each day.

Output of script should be:

```
2002-02-15 2
2002-02-13 1
```

Comment: Share what you have tried so far? Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: `grep RES file | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | uniq -c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
awk '/RES/ { N[$1] += 1; }; END { for (day in N) { print day, N[day] } }' your_input
```

It creates an associative array `N` whose indices are the days of the first field, and whose values are incremented by one for every line matching `RES`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code on a clean bash, it worked, but very slowly

Comment: @NikolayLork, it is not slow, it just prints the resulting table after processing the whole file, which I guess it's huge in your case. Regardless, the solution Cyrus proposed in the comment should be faster nonetheless.